# Why apply() can not be used in shorthand form on package objects?

Tags: scala

On normal objects, I can do the following:

```
object A {
  def apply = "!"
}
A() // "!"
```

But on package objects, this doesn't work:

```
package object A {
  def apply = "?"
}
A.apply // "?"
A() // compile error
    // error: package A is not a value
```

Is there some fundamental limitation? Or is it just an implementation limitation, which I can fix by tweaking the compiler a bit?

Comment: What did you want to do with it? Why not just use normal objects?

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko - for example, to call some method without imports throughout the codebase - if you have package object "monkey" with method "apply", you then would be able to do "monkey()" in any place. That's an example - but I'm also interested why package objects are so different from normal objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way you can do it without apply is this:

```
A.`package`()
```

This is because `A` does not denote a value or a method, and the language specification states that for `f()` to be valid, `f` has to have a method type or a value type with an `apply` method. I have no idea how easily one could "tweak" the compiler to change this, but I doubt it's worth the effort. If you do want to go to such lengths, it would be easier to just add your method to `Predef`.

Comment: How can I add a method to `Predef`?

Comment: @Madoc: you get the source code of the standard library, add your method, and compile it